# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RNDateTimePicker"

Tags: react-native

```
when I start pod install the result :

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RNDateTimePicker":
  In Podfile:
    RNDateTimePicker (from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker`)

Specs satisfying the `RNDateTimePicker (from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

In the Below part of my package.json

{
"name": "NassauTennisMobileApp",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest",
"lint": "eslint ."
},
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.10.1",
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.4.1",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.16.3",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.4",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.7.4",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.3.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.5",
"3.0.0": "^3.0.0",
"indicative": "^7.4.4",
"link": "^0.1.5",
"moment": "^2.27.0",
"native-base": "^2.13.12",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "^0.62.2",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-elements": "^2.2.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
"react-native-material-menu": "^1.1.3",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^10.1.0",
"react-native-paper": "^4.0.1",
"react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
"react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.0",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
"react-native-select-multiple": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.7.0",
"react-native-webview": "^10.8.3",
"react-number-format": "^4.4.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.3",
"redux": "^4.0.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "7.9.6",
"@babel/runtime": "7.9.6",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
"babel-jest": "24.9.0",
"eslint": "6.8.0",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
"react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}

Anybody can help me how can i install POD
Please  Help

Answer (score 3):

node modules-> @react-native-community -> datetimepicker-> RNDateTimePicker.podspec

find the line with this code
`s.platform = '10.0'` or any version

and change it to your current deployment target version like this,

```
s.platform = '9.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by changing to `platform: ios, 11.0` in both `RNDateTimePicker.podspec` and `Podfile` files in `ios` folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case: I Just changed this line in my Podfile:

`platform :ios, '9.0'` -> `platform :ios, '10.0'`